# can the amqplib nodejs package be used ONLY for rabbitmq or for any AMQP communication?

Tags: node.js, npm, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

The RabbitMQ website has a [getting started tutorial for Javascript NodeJS](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html) where it asks to use the amqplib package `npm install amqplib` https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib.

However, the the amqplib package looks like it's more generic rather than being specific to RabbitMQ's implementation of AMQP. So i was wondering can the amqplib nodejs package be used ONLY for rabbitMQ or can it be used for any kind of AMQP communication?

***P.S. This is the first time i am working with queues and rabbitmq and amqp - so don't have much background about this area yet.***

Answer (score 2):

It can be used with brokers that implement AMQP 0.9.1.

RabbitMQ supports AMQP 0.9.1, 0.8 and 1.0